# How can I turn a single element in a list into multiple elements using Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of elements, and each element consists of four separate values that are separated by tabs:

```
['A\tB\tC\tD', 'Q\tW\tE\tR', etc.]
```

What I want is to create a larger list without the tabs, so that each value is a separate element:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', etc.]
```

How can I do that in Python? I need it for my coursework, due tonight (midnight GMT) and I'm completely stumped.

Answer (score 5):

All at once:

```
'\t'.join(['A\tB\tC\tD', 'Q\tW\tE\tR']).split('\t')
```

One at a time:

```
[c for s in ['A\tB\tC\tD', 'Q\tW\tE\tR'] for c in s.split('\t')]
```

Or if all elements are single letters:

```
[c for s in ['A\tB\tC\tD', 'Q\tW\tE\tR'] for c in s[::2]]
```

If there could be quoted tabs then:

```
import csv
rows = csv.reader(['A\t"\t"\tB\tC\tD', 'Q\tW\tE\tR'], delimiter='\t')
[c for s in rows for c in s] # or list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(rows))
```

Answer (score 0):

Homework question?

```
t = ['A\tB\tC\tD', 'Q\tW\tE\tR']
sum((x.split('\t') for x in t),[])
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much, this is a massive help :D

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
t = ['A\tB\tC\tD', 'Q\tW\tE\tR']

t = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(str.split,t))
```

Comment: Use `sum(map(str.split, t), [])` if you are going that route.